# mediaQuery is not working in react-native

Tags: react-native

Media query is not working at some point.

I wrote media query twice already and when write third for the screen size "@media(max-device-width:360) and (max-device-height:640)" .it's not working.

I have just started coding and can't make it work. so any help will be great value to me.

```
    import { MediaQueryStyleSheet } from "react-native-responsive";
      ...//code is here.    
    const styles = MediaQueryStyleSheet.create(
      {
        container: {
          flex: 1
        },
        welcomeImage: {
          width: null,
          height: "83%",
          opacity: 0.5,
          position: "relative",
          resizeMode: "cover",
          alignSelf: "stretch",
          backgroundColor: "#3B3B3B"
        },
        titleContainer: {
          flexDirection: "column",
          alignItems: "center",
          position: "absolute",
        },
        logo: {
          height: 92,
          width: 252,
        },
        tagline: {
          paddingTop: 13,
          alignItems: "center",
          fontSize: 20,
          color: "#FBFBFB",
          textAlign: "center",
          fontFamily: "segoeUI"
        },
      },
      {
        "@media(max-device-width:374) and (max-device-height:811)": {
          welcomeImage: {
            height: "80%"
          },
          logo: {
            width: 226.8,
            height: 82.8,
          },
        }
      },
      {
        "@media(min-device-width:375) and (max-device-height:811)": {
          welcomeImage: {
            height: "80%",
          },
        }
      },
      {
        "@media(max-device-width:360) and (max-device-height:640)": {
          tagline:{
            fontSize:15,
          },    
        }
      },
    );
```

//It doesn't show any error. but also not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem in this line,

```
@media(max-device-width:360) and (max-device-height:640)
```

You are setting media query for `max-width` only.

Media query pattern should be `min-width` to `max-height` like,

```
@media (min-device-width : 360) and (max-device-height : 640)
```

Also make sure you have same pattern for all the media queries.

[Ref](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-responsive)

Comment: Thank you for your solution, i modified my media queries as per your suggestion. Although I am still stuck at the same issue, may be the device pixel values are not getting fetched properly.

Comment: You must write your queries in descending order of `device-width`.

Comment: earlier I used descending order of width which was not responding me correctly. Then I used it in Ascending order.